# AJAX/JSON vs. Server Side Controls

Tags: jquery, ajax, server-side-scripting

I am currently developing a single page application using jQuery and ASP.NET(C#). The diagram below illustrates my current approach for the solution implementation:

[image: solution implementation]

(1) User interacts with webpage, making a request for data, triggering a JQuery event.

(2) AJAX sends request to code-behind.

(3) Code-behind queries database for requested data.

(4) Database returns query results.

(5) Code-behind formats results into JSON file and sends it back to browser.

(6) JQuery parses through JSON file and updates the view.

I have been reading up on how to call code-behind methods using JQuery AJAX requests, and have come to a conclusion which I would like to verify here. It appears as though, by replacing the .html file with a .aspx file, those elements which are configured to function as server-side controls can be directly manipulated in the code-behind (the server). Initially, this seemed preferable to my approach because it would discard the need to create a JSON file and have to browser update the page (i.e.: one less step in the data retrieval process). However, if I were to take this alternative approach, would my solution still be considered an SPA? I.e.: does the server-side code-behind update the existing page in the browser, or does it generate a new page and send it back to the browser. If the former is true, then I will use server-side controls, otherwise I will continue with the approach illustrated above.

(I posted this question on webmasters.stackexchange.com, but was told it was off-topic)

Comment: *"does the server-side code-behind update the existing page in the browser, or does it generate a new page and send it back to the browser"* Depends on what you consider to be a "page". Note that servers don't respond to ajax requests any differently than they do requests for html other than the fact that they may or may not return html for the ajax request. An ajax request is really just an HTTP request, which is no different from requesting index.html.

Comment: Consider a .aspx page containing a button which functions as a server side control. This button, when clicked prints some text onto an empty <div> element. When a user clicks on the button and the server responds, does the server send a new page to the browser, or does it update the existing page (much like how javascript/jquery updates an existing page, rather than generating a new one)?:

Comment: again, i think you're mis-using the word "page". generally "single page application" (SPA) simply means the browser doesn't refresh, and all communication to and from the server is done through ajax. What route that ajax request hits is irrelevant as far as determining whether or not the app is a SPA. In your situation you were calling all routes "pages".

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by "route"?

Comment: rout, endpoint, server page, whatever you prefer to call it. it isn't really a "page" in the sense of a web page unless the browser renders it.

Comment: Ok. Taking my previous example, would the browser refresh? My assumption is that there is no need for AJAX when using server-side controls because everything is handled by the server directly; is this assumption correct?

Comment: i'm not familiar with server-side controls.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103989/discussion-between-kevin-b-and-aluthren).